# Compiler three address code program in c language

Tags: compiler-construction

I don't understand, a+a*(b-c)+d*(b-c) this expression how compile? I need this in C language.[image]

Comment: I can't even tell what *form* an answer would take, much less what it should contain.

Comment: @ScottHunter I hope he is trying to know how it is being executed.

Comment: No I need solution in C language, The code in C.

Comment: @mhtamun What code? The entire code needed to go from a string/file containing expressions like that to a three address code representation? Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any language, in mathematical operations, braces **()** will be given top priority. So is something is written in **()**, it will be executed first. Later * and **/** will be given next priority. So if **()** is not given then multiplication and division will be executed. Then addition and subtraction will be executed.

**a+a*(b-c)+d*(b-c)**.

Here (b-c) will be executed first because of braces. Then **a*(b-c) and d*(b-c)** will be executed. Finally all results are added.

Comment: I need a solution in C language how this works behind can u give?

Comment: What do you mean by solution?

Comment: I gave an idea of how this works. So try yourself.

Comment: Solution by C Code program.

Comment: It is an mathematical expression.

Comment: What do you mean by program for mathematical expression